# Keep a variable in memory between program runs

Tags: c++, memory, gnuplot

In the `c++` program that I am trying to write I would need to update a 2D array and then plot it (for plotting I have been using `gnuplot`) for a pretty big number of times.
I would like, if possible, to avoid having a huge file in which I would write the matrix for every step of the evolution to plot everything afterwards.

My intention was to do a `gnuplot` script able to run the program to evolve the matrix once and then print it and then iterate. But to do so I would need to give to the program access to the matrix calculated in the prior step and I cannot figure out an efficient way to do it. Being able to keep the matrix in memory between runs and passing only a pointer from one step to the other seems fast but I do not know if it is possible.

Do you know if it is possible to keep a variable in memory between runs or do you have alternative suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: You could store the data on a ramdisk/ramdrive (in-memory filesystem)

Comment: If the file is read from/written to disk and you have enough memory it might be cashed anyway

Comment: write to stdout and pipe it to gnuplot directly

Answer (score 2):

You should open `Gnuplot` inside your `c++` program, and communicate with it using a FIFO as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71906265/get-variables-from-gnuplot-to-c/71907938#71907938).

After that, you can polt your array for example:

```cpp
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "plot '-' nonuniform matrix with image\n";
/*... filling ss with your array*/
ss << "e\ne\n\n";
fprintf(gp, ss.str().c_str());
fflush(gp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `memory-mapped` file.

`Boost` provides for a `cross-platform` `shared-memory` file.

Check out the [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.mapped_file).